# Display GeoPDF's coordinates in metres created using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopdf

I exported a GeoPDF map using QGIS 3.10.1. My project coordinates system is in BNG (EPSG 27700) and so the CRS in map grid properties in the layout. In other words, source data, the project CRS and the grid properties are in metres.

[image]

But the PDF I created earlier doesn't show the units in metres when it is opened using Adobe reader (Geospatial Location Tool). And I would like to see the coordinates of the GeoPDF in metres (Easting and Northing).

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have a created a grid on your layout that is in DMS and not BNG but it is unclear from your posting.  Can you  add more detail.  Maybe include an image? Without more clarity your posting will be closed by the moderators.

Comment: No my grid is not in DMS. Please refer the images.